# Using animated Gif in Acr.UserDialog in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, mobile, xamarin, loading, gif

I am using the Acr.UserDialog package to add a loading 'screen' to my app, which I am developing using Xamarin Forms. I am using it in someway like that:

```
var loading = UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Carregando", null, null, true, MaskType.Gradient);

loading.Show();
(...)
loading.Hide();
```

It is working fine. However, I need to add an animated Gif to this loading 'screen'. It is possible to do that? If so, how can I do it? It is the same procedure to Android and IOs?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the WebView for the effect. It works on all platforms.
You need first to write an Xml file for the animation.
This is my sample for the Xml file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >

   <WebView
         android:id="@+id/webLoadingIcon"
         android:layout_width="44dp"
         android:layout_height="44dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
         android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
         android:background="#00000000"
         />

   </LinearLayout>
```

The "webLoadingIcon" represents the name of your .gif photo you want to use.
Then create a method that uses and loads up the .gif photo on the screen.
This is a sample:

```
   void LoadAnimatedGif()
   {
        webLoadingIcon = currentView.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webLoadingIcon);
        // expects to find the 'loading_icon_small.gif' file in the 'root' of the assets folder, compiled as AndroidAsset.
        webLoadingIcon.LoadUrl(string.Format("file:///android_asset/loading_icon_small.gif"));
        // this makes it transparent so you can load it over a background
        webLoadingIcon.SetBackgroundColor(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        webLoadingIcon.SetLayerType(LayerType.Software, null);
   }
```

Hope I helped you a little bit! :)